# Programming Arduino DUE without IDE (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, arduino, arm

Is there any current, relatively simple way to compile and upload full .c/.cpp files for the Arduino DUE on Linux?

I'm beginning to regularly run into issues using the boilerplate code they provide around the sketches and so far, there is very little in the way of documentation or alternative IDE support for the arduino 1.5 SDK...  That and the official 1.0.5 IDE is hopelessly [broken](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arduino) for linux right now (serial port issues among other things).

Comment: It depends on your linux distribution, but there is [this](http://www.linuxcircle.com/2013/05/15/programming-and-uploading-arduino-sketch-without-ide/) and [this](http://www.mjoldfield.com/atelier/2009/02/arduino-cli.html).

Comment: It appears that neither of those cover the 1.5 SDK required for the DUE. The second one has it wallpapering their issue tracker but god knows how long it will take to implement.  It looks like they're taking their time switching branches.

Comment: I'm going to add that for those who are interested in this, getting a JTAG programmer and then compiling .elf files with the atmel software framework then uploading them directly greatly simplifies the process in some ways.  This is how the chips are designed to be programmed anyway, without being on a dedicated development board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a great example [here](http://www.atwillys.de/content/cc/using-custom-ide-and-system-library-on-arduino-due-sam3x8e/?lang=en).

He explains what you need and how to use it to be able to upload to the due from the terminal of a linux box.

He has done a great job in helping you set up an environment to compile and upload your c programs onto the SAM3X8E. He even gives you a makefile and sample code. What more could you ask for?

Give it a try, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can program in c/c++ for the arduio, the arduino does not "use" c/c++ code alone per se.  When you use the IDE for arduino, a few libraries are linked when compiled to give you the "arduino" functions like setup(), and loop() as well as constants such as HIGH and LOW.  The arduino language is based off a language called Processing which is written in c.

If you are having troubles with the Arduino IDE, it might help to download an older version.  Check out the [Previous Releases](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases) page on their website.

If that still doesn't work, you could try to build it from the source code. https://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/BuildingArduino

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing as I really don't like IDE like Eclipse. And I didn't want to rely on Arduino environment. Just something minimalist under ubuntu.

For libraries, I downloaded the ASF (Atmel Software Framework) here http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrsoftwareframework.aspx

For compiling, I installed gcc-arm-embedded from here https://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-arm-embedded. This provides gcc-arm-none-eabi.

The last part is 'bossac', the upload tool (just do an apt-get install bossa-cli).

Then, just use Vim or your fav editor, adapt a config.mk (configuration of the ASF's MakeFile) for your own project and once okay, upload the .bin to your board with bossac.

Note that bossac has to be run as root (sudo) if you want it to detect your usb port (/dev/ACM0).

After few days playing with examples provided by the ASF library, you'll be able to use a small subset of headers files (only basic definitions like registers names, bits function names in registers ...) to help you and do all the rest by yourself. I personally even don't use 'drivers' files anymore. I directly access registers with my own methods to get smaller code.